# Monitor Memory Use in Delphi App

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, monitoring

I inherited a very large subsystem from a programmer that left the company and the first order of business is to stop the process from running out of memory.

Basically, it is a loop through a dataset, within which we create and destroy a data module that goes off and does lots of work. As long as this data module is created, you can see memory use climbing all the time in Task Manager until it blows up. I seem to recall from an article I read years ago that one shouldn't fully trust what is reported by Task Manager, as the values are estimates and not real-time. So I am looking for alternatives.

Here's what I have tried:

1. ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True in my main project file, but it returns nothing. So either it doesn't monitor memory leaked in packages that are loaded dynamically, or the memory gets freed before the app closes.
2. AQTime. This is supposed to be a very **wow** product, but I find it completely underwhelming. If I use the allocation profiler, I end up with hundreds of lines containing nothing useful. Just a memory address, size and something along the lines of "VCL standard allocation." It supposedly breaks down the information by routine, but I just get a flat list with no routine info whatsoever. So I don't think it works.

Is there another tool that can help me trace where this memory is allocated and not freed? I've been commenting out little bits of functionality all over the place to see where the problem goes away and checked that everything that is explicitly allocated gets freed, but I still have a leak and it can be quite a frustrating process.

Comment: How heavy are datasets loaded? Are you sure that is not the amount of data to be too great?

Comment: ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown on reports leaks of memory that have not been freed at shutdown. Reporting leaks whilst running is more difficult.

Comment: ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown shows some data if you create a memleak yourself? Like just "TComponent.Create" in you .dpr?

Comment: AQTime was the WOW product for me for sure. I think you should spend more time understanding it, since in my long search for a more decent memory leak debugger was in vain.

Comment: @Cobus, are you sure you are running out of memory and not running out of resources (window/font/bitmap handles)?

Comment: @Marco The outer dataset is quite big, but memory use is very reasonable after it has been loaded. When looping through the dataset,  the data module is created and destroyed within that loop. That is where the memory keep ticking up and up. The data module is freed, as are all the data that it allocates. Yet memory use consistently increases during this loop.

Comment: @Cobus, sounds exactly like the issue I described in my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe that was only for the BDE. Nevertheless, I think the issue is that as you are looping through the dataset you are keeping it in memory. I think that dbExpress by design has unidirectional datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I absolutely would use AQTime, and NOTHING ELSE to determine memory usage information.  Here is an example of the memory usage information I would expect you could find:

1. Exact line that allocates memory with GetMem, TObject.Create.
2. Nice counters of object counts and total memory used by various class types.

First things first, let's get the obvious things out of the way:

A. You have to follow AQTime's instructions and set your project settings up, including your compiler and linker settings, as documented well in the help files. Especially you need the Turbo Debugger (TD32) symbols in your linker options, and all the other options setup as you would set up for any other debug build of your project.

B. You should try a tutorial first, before you use this with your own app.

In short, I've used AQTime heavily, and when I've had problems, they have been solveable,  so don't give up yet on AQTime.  If you can't get your big app working, start by learning how to test a small app, a demo, or a tutorial exercise.

**Update:** I have just tested it out myself, and I find that I am having trouble even making a basic demo of AQTime 7 with Allocation profiler work as described. I am using AQTime 7.10.380 pro.

Answer (score 11):

FastMM includes a simple GUI which displays memory usage while the application is running.

An example project is located in the `Demos/Usage Tracker` directory.

Comment: +1 You can just include that usage tracker form to your own project, and i'll show you a live graphical represenation of your memory that's constantly updated. Pretty neat. I usually include that between `{$IFDEF DEBUG}..{$ENDIF}`, so that it's only included in my debug builds.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor an application memory usage you could use some of the [sysinternals](http://www.sysinternals.org) tools (process explorer, VMMap, Rammap) to look at it from an operating system perspective, but tools like AQTime will actually tell you who allocated memory, when and where, as long as you configure and use it properly - it has an initial steep learning curve, read the documentation carefully, it's not a tool "run and read the results".
It may not be any leak to blow up the app, it could be it is just loading and keeping in memory too much data.
There are good chances you're loading a huge dataset in memory, or soemthing alike, for example a bidirectional dataset will cache previous records to allow for backwards navigation, a unidrectional one will not and will use far less memory. Some libraries are more efficient than others when setting up memory for varchar fields and the like (some may always allocate the varchar field size, other may be smarter and just allocate the space for a given record field, although that makes management of record changes more difficult). It could be intermediate result kept in memory for too long, the wrong choice of data structure or too much recursion... difficult to say without looking at the code.

Comment: "as long as you configure and use it properly" - that's the key. It will give what you want if you learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Found some tools here on About.com for Delphi mem leaks: http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/aatpmemleak.htm

Comment: I saw this earlier today, but two of these tools have not been updated significantly since Delphi 7 and the other two are really not aimed at tracking memory issues. Looks like the consensus is that I should try AQTime again, this time following the instructions more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that you are holding the dataset in memory as you loop through it, and if you have hundreds of thousands (or millions) of records this can exceed 1 GB. I seem to recall a dataset property, UniDirectional, which ensures that memory can be released as you go because you cannot go back to the previous record in the dataset (like normal) if this property is set.

**Edit:** I think that this was only for the BDE, but dbExpress uses Unidirectional datasets by default if I am not mistaken.